# creating derived object using base constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, csv

I'm reading a line from a CSV file into a vector, I then want to pass this vector into a correct derived class so create an object with the correct private properties. However how do I pass the vector up to the base class, instead of just to the derived object?

Base class:

```
class Material
{
public:
    Material() ;
    virtual ~Material() ;

    void addNewMaterial();

private:

    std::string type;
    std::string format;
    int idNumber;
    std::string filmTitle;
    std::string audioFormat;
    float runtime;
    std::string language;
    float retailPrice;
    std::string subtitles;
    std::string frameAspect;
    std::string bonusFeatures;
};
```

derived class:

```
class Disk : public Material
{
public:
   Disk(); 
   ~Disk();

private:

   std::string packaging;

   std::string audioFormat;
   std::string language;     //multiple language tracks
   std::string subtitles;   //subtitles in different languages
   std::string bonusFeatures; //bonus features

};
```

2nd derived class

```
    class ssDVD : public Disk
{
public:
    ssDVD(std::vector<std::string>);
    ~ssDVD();

private:

    //plastic box

};
```

I want to create a new ssDVD with the properties of the base Material class which uses the constructor to setup the variables. How do I access and change these from the derived object?

Answer (score 1):

Your derived class's constructor will need to pass its parameter to its superclass's constructor.

First of all, in most cases it's more efficient to pass non-POD function parameters as constant references, in order to avoid copying large objects by value:

```
class ssDVD : public Disk {
public:
   ssDVD(const std::vector<std::string> &);

   // ...
};
```

Then, the constructor passes its parameter to the superclass's constructor, by value:

```
ssDVD::ssDVD(const std::vector<std::string> &v) : Disk(v)
   // Whatever else the constructor needs to do
{
   // Ditto...
}
```

Of course, then you will have to have `Disk`'s constructor do the same, to pass the parameter to the base class.

And to close the loop, if you were passing all these parameters by value, a separate copy of the vector would be made by each constructor. Very inefficient. By using constant references, no copies get made.